# Blank pages when converting to PDF with TuesPechkin

Tags: c#, pdf, pechkin

I'd like to convert several different web pages into one PDF document. I found Pechkin / TuesPechkin, which has been a wonderful discovery, but I am running into one problem: only the last `Object` gets converted, and all the other PDF pages are blank. What could be causing this problem?

```
var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
{
    GlobalSettings =
    {
        Margins =
        {
            All = 1.375,
            Unit = Unit.Centimeters
        }
    }
};

// Each "page" variable contains one HTML page
foreach (var page in pages)
    document.Objects.Add(new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = page.Html });

// Create converter
var converter = Factory.Create();

// Convert!
var result = converter.Convert(document);

// Save
File.WriteAllBytes(path, result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is a confirmed bug.
https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/issues/23

I ended up solving the issue by generating one page at a time and merging the pages with iTextSharp.